# Solaris /proc high physical memory usgae

Tags: solaris-10

I'm using Solaris (Solaris 10 5/08 s10x_u5wos_10 X86) to run a jboss application.

```
root@dev3-be3:/proc/17197$ ps -ef | grep java
    root 24685 24670   2 12:13:46 pts/10    225:54 java -Dprogram.name=run_with_profiler.sh -server -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:tr

root@dev3-be3:/proc/24685$ du -sh * | grep G
 1.0G   as
  18G   fd
root@dev3-be3:/proc/24685$

root@dev3-be3:/proc/24685$ prstat | grep 24685
24685 root     1041M  991M cpu0     0    0   4:01:35  51% java/200

root@dev3-be3:/proc/24685$ df -k
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/                    124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /
/dev                 124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /dev
/export/home         124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /export/home
/lib                 124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /lib
/opt                 124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /opt
/platform            124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /platform
/sbin                124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /sbin
/usr                 124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /usr
/usr/local           124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /usr/local
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
objfs                      0       0       0     0%    /system/object
swap                 6115848     272 6115576     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                     124960305 110368903 13341799    90%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                         0       0       0     0%    /dev/fd
swap                 6132272   16696 6115576     1%    /tmp
swap                 6115588      12 6115576     1%    /var/run
192.168.150.32:/sftp 461928730 38771266 423157464     9%    /sftp
root@dev3-be3:/proc/24685$
```

Why this /proc/pid/fd has high physical memory? This gets cleared after shutting down server.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ps` or `prstat` to figure out how much memory a process is using. Using `du` on `/proc` pseudo file system is at best dubious.

Answer (score 1):

Running 'du' on /proc (which is a virtual filesystem) is nonsensical.

There is a very good description of /proc found in its manpage, proc(4).

If your real question is "why is my java application using so much memory?"
then you are better off check the manpages to see what effect the profiler
has on memory usage. You should also check what version of java you're using
(memory usage has improved greatly in later releases). It's probably worthwhile
looking into the heap, too (see pmap).

Then you should ask your developers what they're doing and whether it's all
necessary.